# possibility to add the category within the message?

Tags: jboss-logging

Currently, I must use this:

```
Messages msg = Logger.getMessageLogger(Messages.class, "org.messages");
```

With this approach, I lost the information in which class the logger was called (therefore it is normally recommended **to use one logger per class**).

Is there any way to adjust the category per method level? For example:

```
// the category tag does not exist
@LogMessage
@Message(value="test %s", category="%s")
void status(String test, String category);
```

and use it like this:

```
// prints "org.test" as category instead of "org.messages"
Messages.msg.status("hi", "org.test");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really follow. The way you're getting the logger per category is correct. What information are you losing?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. My fault. Thanks!